# Sorting data by parent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have table like this

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| id_struc    | id_emply    | id_boss   |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |       1     |     0     | 
|           3 |       2     |     3     |
|           6 |       4     |     1     |
|           7 |       5     |     1     |
|           9 |       6     |     3     |
|          10 |       3     |     4     |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I want to sort it so I can get something like this.

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| id_struc    | id_emply    | id_boss   |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |       1     |     0     |
|           6 |       4     |     1     |
|           7 |       5     |     1     |
|          10 |       3     |     4     |
|           3 |       2     |     3     |
|           9 |       6     |     3     |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

It's sort by `id_boss`. So every `id_emply` couldn't be at the top of their bosses. Can I possibly do that?

Comment: sorry but you result is not order by id_boss, id_boss:3 is after id_boss:4

Comment: it looks like order by id_emply, id_boss to me?

Comment: I meant I want to sort it but the employee could be at the top of their bosses

Comment: In mysql you do not sort data directly in data tables, you order resultsets of your queries. You are probably looking for a query that would produce such an ordered resultset.

Comment: a good question has some code.

Comment: What do you mean by _at the top of their bosses_? Can you please expand/correct your example to make your desired result more clear? As of now I don't see any consistent sorting.

Comment: @marvin, I guess  user2999081 means hierarchical recursive query.

Comment: Which version of MySql? I'm just asking because 8.0 supports [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive), otherwise you're looking for something like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: why downvote?  this is a good question... who ever is downvoter please try to understand the question first. then only downvote

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a query like this:

```
select t.*
from t
left join t b on t.id_boss = b.id_emply
order by b.id_boss, t.id_emply;
```

[`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51108d/1)